# Adjusting the height and width of a screenshot with html2canvas?

Tags: javascript, shiny, html2canvas, shinyapps

[image: I'd like to remove the highlighted yellow portion in the bottom, which should make the important parts of the png biggerand more clear.] Here is a reproducible example. I have tried adding in the height and width options, shown [here](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration/), but they don't affect my screenshot. Is this because I'm using body as the element? I'd like to just remove the bottom of my shinyapp from the screenshot. As you can probably tell, I am new to javascript and coding in general, and any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    # include html2canvas library
    tags$script(src = "http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"),
    # script for creating the prompt for download
    tags$script(
      "
            function saveAs(uri, filename) {

                var link = document.createElement('a');

                if (typeof link.download === 'string') {

                    link.href = uri;
                    link.download = filename;

                    //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
                    document.body.appendChild(link);

                    //simulate click
                    link.click();

                    //remove the link when done
                    document.body.removeChild(link);

                } else {

                    window.open(uri);

                }
            }
            "
    )
  ),
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("screenshot","Take Screenshot"),
  dataTableOutput("table"),
  plotOutput("plot")


)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$screenshot,{
    shinyjs::runjs(
      'html2canvas(document.querySelector("body")).then(canvas => {
                saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), "shinyapp.png");
           });'
    )
  })


  output$table <- renderDataTable(iris)

  output$plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = iris) + 
                              geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What do you mean by bottom of your shiny app? Do you just need the table to be added to the screenshot?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear - in my app I have some white space and commentary at the bottom of the page that I'd like the screenshot to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by **remove the bottom of my shinyapp from the screenshot**. Here is a working example to print just the table or the plot image as screenshots.

```
# To print only the table in the screenshot
shinyjs::runjs(
      'html2canvas(document.querySelector("table")).then(canvas => {
                saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), "shinyapp.png");
           });')

# To print only the image in the screenshot
shinyjs::runjs(
      'html2canvas(document.querySelector("img")).then(canvas => {
                saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), "shinyapp.png");
           });')
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! For my app, I don't have a specific table or graph to exclude - but I just want to exclude the white space and commentary at the bottom of the app.

Would it be easiest to adjust the height, or use ignoreElements and pass in the individual elements I don't want included? Which I'm not sure if I can use ignoreElements for white space.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hey @Siddharth I just updated my post with the screenshot, but had to censor some info. I just want to remove the highlighted yellow portion at the bottom. However, adding the height option to my screenshot has no affect - which I believe may be because I'm using the "body" as my element?

Do you know of a method for excluding certain portions in html2canvas?